# Webgl drawing letter F

Tags: html, webgl

I get the right shape when I use gl.LINE_LOOP but when I try to use gl.TRIANGLE_FAN I get a odd looking shape. I have attached my vertices as well.

```
vertices = new Float32Array([
      0,    0,      0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0,    0.7,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.5,  0.7,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.5,  0.6,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.2,  0.6,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.2,  0.5,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.5,  0.5,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.5,  0.4,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.2,  0.4,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
      0.2,  0,    0.0, 1.0, 1.0
      ]);


rect1 = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect1 );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;

// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer



var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 5, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vVertexColor");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 5, FSIZE * 2);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

A triangle fan cannot work on that shape, since it only works for shapes that have a central vertex that all other vertices are connected to (you can look this up on Google or Wikipedia: [triangle fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_fan)). For a shape like that, you will need individual triangles or two triangle strips (look this up on wiki as well, there's a link at the bottom of the triangle fan article).

I would suggest to use gl.TRIANGLES and add an index array (that is, use gl.drawElements). I recommend to read a basic tutorial on WebGL rendering like this one here: [Creating 3D objects using WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL).